# How exactly do soft shadows get generated using a voxel cone tracing rendering technique?

Tags: opengl, raytracing, rendering, global-illumination, voxelization

Let's assume we have voxelized a scene, and all of our materials have an opacity level of 1. The reuslt would then look like:

[image]

If we raytraced the final volume that gets generated after rasterization.

Now, we wish to generate soft shadows, which is done by increasing the LOD sample level as we move further away from the source, sampling at discrete intervals and adding opacity values until we reach an opacity of 1.

If my understanding is correct that is.

Could soemone that is familiar with this technique give a better explanation and correct any mistakes I have made? Pictures and diagrams are appreciated too.

Comment: Some helpful diagrams: https://github.com/jose-villegas/VCTRenderer